# canOpenUrl always return NO in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to check if my app is available in phone then it open otherwise show alert msg. but canOpen url always failed even app is successfully opened with url.

First App from where i want to open another app
here is my Code:

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:"abc://"];
if ([application canOpenURL:URL]) {
  [application openURL:URL options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
      NSLog(@"Opened url");
    }
  }];
} else {
  NSLog(@"app cannot open.");

}
```

[image]

[image: development target]

Second app:
[URL Types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK6zS.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `CFBundleURLTypes` in your `Info.plist` file:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
   <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>abc</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Nothing happened

Comment: what do you mean by nothing happened? the `canOpenUrl` still returns `NO`?

Comment: I am getting this error: **-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "abc://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme abc"**

Comment: do you have 2 apps, like `A` and `B`, and in `A` you want to check if `B` is installed?

Answer (score -1):

Hi Guys i have got solution so i am posting it here so if you got same error like this **-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "abc://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme abc"** you might avoid to do same mistake.

Actually i have Sub project in my Main project and just because of it there are multiple info.plist so i was adding **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** in Sub Project instead of main project.

So make sure two things:

1). you are adding **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** in main project's plist

2). iOS Development target must be greater or equal to  9.0